# Phpunit throws an error when testing a form which has a partial view in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have recently started writing unit tests, so the concept itself is still not really clear for me, I'm trying to learn it by writing unit testing on a project that I'm currently working on.

I have tested the authentication, and it's all good; however, when I want to test a form submission, it throws the following erro:

`'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: errors'`

When I was debugging I came across that the view variable `$errors` is not defined for Phpunit. The form I'm testing was abstracted to a partial view to reference from it for `CREATE/UPDATE`, but it turns out that Phpunit can't handle the partial views.

I have tested it when I comment the `@include('view.name')` form the view I'm testing it passes it.

My question is whether there are any workaround to this. How can I test the views that has partial views?

**Exception**:

```
Caused by
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: errors' in                  /Users/***/Developpement/***/storage/framework/views/36f0b5638ab33     be6eca70d4986f07ad2:2
Stack trace:
#0     /Users/***/Developpement/***/storage/framework/views/36f0b5638ab33    be6eca70d4986f07ad2(2):     Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined     varia...', '/Users/***/D...', 2, Array)
#1     /Users/***/Developpement/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illumina    te/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(42): include('/Users/***/D...')
#2     /Users/***/Developpement/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illumina    te/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(58): ***        minate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Users/***/D...', Array)
#3         /Users/***/Developpement/***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illumina    te/View/View.php(138): Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine-    >get('/Users/***/D...', Array)
```

**Parent View**

```
<div class="container">

    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.festivals.create.post', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

    <legend>Create</legend>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="   {{route('admin.festivals.list')}}">Home</a>
    </div>

     // HERE IS THE LINE WHEN I COMMENT IT IT WORKS
    {{--@include('admin.festivals._form')--}}

        {!! Form::submit('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary col-md-2']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}


</div>
```

**Partial View**

```
<div class="form-group row {{ $errors->has('start_date') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
<label class="control-label col col-md-2" for="start_date">Start Date</label>

<div class="col col-md-4">
    {!! Form::datepicker('start_date', (isset($festival)) ? $festival->start_date : null) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('start_date', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>
```

Comment: After a day of digging I have found that phpunit somehow not able to check with the if statement in one line  `$errors->has('start_date') ? 'has-error' : ''` and then it has to check the `$errors` first and then you can check  with `has` function so the check should be like this `@if(isset($errors) && $errors->has('start_date')) has-error @endif` so this really annoying does anybody know any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround other than checking with `isset()`. Unit testing is intended to test back-end, not forms.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing):

> In procedural programming, a unit could be an entire module, but it is more commonly an individual function or procedure. In object-oriented programming, a unit is often an entire interface, such as a class, but could be an individual method.

If you want to test behaviour of forms and user interfaces, use a front-end test framework, such as [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).